# Call onTextChanged function when javascript fills value in textbox

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a textbox whose value is populated by a javascript. onTextChanged event is not fired in this case. Is there any way i could call the function to let know that textbox value had been updated

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_FromDate" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server"  OnTextChanged="SaveData" />
 <input id="Testbutton" type="button" onclick="return showDateCalendar(this);" class="dateButtonWidth"
                                           style="background-image: url(Images/Calendar.jpg);"   />
```

on button click the javascript populates date in the textbox. How do i call onTextChangedEvent.

Comment: SaveData is defined in Javascript or in ASP?

Comment: it is defined in ASP .cs file of aspx

Comment: Could you add the code for SaveData? Are you using updatepanels somewhere?

Comment: it simply sends the value in textbox to database along with other values of control on page

Comment: it is inside update panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

```
<head runat="server">
   <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="smc"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_FromDate" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="TextBox_FromDate_TextChanged" />
            <input id="Testbutton" type="submit" onclick="showDateCalendar(this);" class="dateButtonWidth" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what javascript function should  be called from textbox as the data is not onChange/keypress. It just gets populated with date (populated using javascript on button click)

Comment: this is still not calling server side function

Comment: @Eve my last edit works charmly on my machine. Try like above.

Comment: The calendar does not pop up and populate the textbox if return is removed. But postback occurs. Is there anyway to avoid this

Comment: this works perfectly. I added the postback call when i select a date in the calendar which is a javascript. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a trigger to the UpdatePanel:

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="TextBox_FromDate" EventName="SaveData" />
</Triggers>
```

Comment: I want the server side code to execute when textbox value changes and not want to replace with javascript instead